# What unusual thing takes place when I step into a Control.Visible = true assignment?

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, visibility, step-into

I have an UserControl that is made Visible. One of its custom properties is set to `true` somewhere I do not know. All I know is that after setting its `Visible` property to another value (`true`), the custom property is `true`. It is wrong that its value is set to `true`, it should remain `false` like it was before.

I am using .NET Framework 4.6.1. I have searched on StackOverflow and I did not find something useful. I tried using the debugger and the Watches window, this is how I found the information presented.

I debugged the program, and the value changes precisely when I step into the `Visible = true` attribute, before other code is shown. The other code is the `OnPaint` handler of my UserControl, and there, in the first line of code, the custom property already has this wrong value. There is no way to find what happens internally after stepping into the Visible assignment and before the custom property takes the value `true`. I guess it is something like an `Application.DoEvents()` call or another thread. How can I debug this so that I get to the code that changes the value of my custom property?

I have read [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.visible?view=netframework-4.6.1) and I did not find something useful.

```
internal void SetChildVisible(ClockData td, bool v)
{
    foreach (IClockView tv in td.MyTimerViews)
    {
        if (tv is ClockControl tc &&
            tv.GetClocksView() == MyClockListView)
        {
            tc.Visible = v;
            break;
        }
    }
    MyClockListView.RefreshDisplay();
}
```

I would like to have some option somewhere in Visual Studio so I can debug situations like this.

Comment: Try to uncheck checkbox _Step over properties and operations_ in _Debugging_ -> _General_ options tab.

Comment: Do you have the source code for the UserControl?

Comment: @tgolisch Yes, I do have the source code of the UserControl.

Comment: Have you tried putting a break-point on the getter and setter for the custom property and any underlying code?

Comment: Setting the Visible property of UC, causes a call to [CreateControl()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,5827) (reference source) for the UC and the its child controls. See whether this can change anything in your custom properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem by putting a breakpoint in the custom property's setter. The debugger steps into the setter before the `Visible` property of the `Control` starts being set. In the setter the property was already set to `false`, so no change was executed, so I stepped out to see where the property was being changed from true to false the last time.

The custom property is a redirect to a subcontrol's custom property for which the code was the following:

```
internal bool ShowCheckBox
{
    get
    {
        return cb.Visible;
    }
    set
    {
        if (cb.Visible != value)
        {
            cb.Visible = value;
            OnShowCheckBoxChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem was that I was setting the `cb.Visible` property and, before that thread which makes it in/visible finished, I was setting the `ShowCheckBox` property again and `cb.Visible` was still having the old value. The solution was to change the above code into the following:

```
internal bool _ShowCheckBox = true;
internal bool ShowCheckBox
{
    get
    {
        return _ShowCheckBox;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_ShowCheckBox != value)
        {
            _ShowCheckBox = value;
            OnShowCheckBoxChanged();
        }
    }
}
```